# A script /etc/profile.d/{script1}.sh doesn't work correctly

Tags: linux, zsh, environment-variables, path, etc

```
cat /etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/atlassian/plugin-sdk/bin
```

```
ls -al /etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 48 Apr 17 21:36 /etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.sh
```

```
ls -al /opt/atlassian/plugin-sdk/bin 
total 408
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Apr 17 21:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Apr 17 21:37 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3534 Apr 17 21:36 atlas-clean
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3506 Apr 17 21:36 atlas-compile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8460 Apr 17 21:36 atlas-create-bamboo-plugin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5985 Apr 17 21:36 atlas-create-bamboo-plugin-module
.................................
```

1. How is that script from `/etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.sh` supposed to work? Is it me who's supposed to call it **each time, manually**? Or is it the system that'll trigger it somehow?

   Anyway, none of the files of `/opt/atlassian/plugin-sdk/bin` are visible in the `PATH`, in the terminal

   However, after I call `/etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.sh` manually, even multiple times, nothing will change at all:

   ```
   echo $PATH
   ........... (`/opt/atlassian/plugin-sdk/bin` isn't here)
   ```
2. Why? What's the matter?

update1:

I'm actually using `zsh`, not bash. However, after

```
sudo cp /etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.sh /etc/profile.d/atlassian-plugin-sdk.zsh
```

and after restarting the shell, nothing has changed: the `/opt/atlassian/plugin-sdk/bin` directory hasn't been appended into `PATH` still

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` are typically sourced by `/etc/profile` when a login bourne shell (e.g. sh, bash) starts up.  If you look in `/etc/profile`, you'll probably see something like this (copied from /etc/profile on my Debian system):

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

This sources all the `.sh` files in /etc/profile.d/, so that they run in (and can affect) the environment of the current shell.

`zsh` doesn't run /etc/profile by default (unless run as `sh` - see `man zsh` and search for COMPATIBILITY), so doesn't execute the scripts in /etc/profile.d/ either.   You could edit `/etc/zsh/profile` and make it source them if you wanted, but zsh isn't exactly sh - it's mostly compatible, but (depending on what, exactly, is in /etc/profile.d/) there may be some odd, unintended side-effects.

If all you want is to add the atlassian directory to your PATH, it's probably easier to just add that to your `~/.zshrc` or, if you want it to apply to all users running zsh, one of the startup files in `/etc/zsh`.

Comment: in `zsh`, you can do `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'` for `/etc/profile` to be sourced in sh emulation which should minimise the incompatibilities with the POSIX sh syntax. Functions defined whilst in sh emulation will also retain the emulation mode. See `info zsh emulate` for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in `/etc/zsh/zprofile` I have `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'`. But still, the PATH won't get updated with the `atlassian/bin`. Why not?

Comment: @perelium, have you logged out and logged back in since? You may want to run `zsh -x --login` to see what zsh does upon login. That might give you a clue as to why it's not sourcing that file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas when I do "log out / log in"  - it'll work thereafter. But then if I run  a new terminal - no, it will no longer work. What's the matter?

Comment: the output of `zsh -x --login` contains  `/opt/atlassian/plugin-sdk/bin`